# SSL Form Submission Redirect?

Tags: forms, ssl, cakephp, https, nearlyfreespeech

When submitting a form with HTTPS the form is for some reason sent to '/', even though the rendered form's action is set to the correct route/method. The url is still correct too - I'm seeing my root page, with a '/contact' url. If I set HTTPS to 'Off' and try the form again with plain HTTP it works fine.

I'm not sure, but I think this issue cropped up the other day when I set up a new cert from Comodo. It happened out of the blue, with code that used to work and has not been changed.

The project is a basic LAMP stack, running on shared hosting from NearlyFreeSpeech.net, and using the CakePHP framework.

I believe it is the same problem discussed in these two threads:

http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/form-submit-never-reaching-controller-action/1744/13
https://members.nearlyfreespeech.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9169&highlight=ssl+form